# How do i specify the min bound of an Integer

Tags: haskell

I am trying to solve an exercise question from [the Haskell Book](http://haskellbook.com/) and wondering what minimum value should I specify in the start accumulator so I can find Max of DBNumber using foldr?

I can't specify minBound::Integer as there is no lower bound. I can probably find this by other means but wondering if i can use foldr as below?

```
import Data.Time

data DatabaseItem = DbString String | DbNumber Integer | DbDate UTCTime deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

theDatabase :: [DatabaseItem]
theDatabase = [DbDate (UTCTime (fromGregorian 1911 5 1) 
                      (secondsToDiffTime 34123)),
               DbNumber -9001,
               DbString "Hello World",
               DbNumber -9002,
               DbNumber -109001,
               DbDate (UTCTime (fromGregorian 1921 5 1) (secondsToDiffTime 34123))]



maxDbNumber xs = foldr (\x y -> case x of 
                       DbNumber z | z > y -> z
                       otherwise -> y) (minBound::Integer) xs
```

Comment: You specify whatever value your function wants to return for an empty list.

Comment: @n.m. sorry can you give me an example? how is empty list going to be useful when i want max from available list of numbers

Comment: You are supposed to return the maximal element of a list, but empty lists do not have any maximal element. So you need to decide somehow what you want to compute if the input list is empty. I can't really help you with this decision. You might say "I don't care about empty lists and I will let my function crash if the input list is empty". You might say "I don't care about lists that contain negative numbers so I will return -1 for empty lists". Or you might say "my maximum is not a simple integer but something smarter". Or lots of other things really. But it's *your* decision.

Comment: If you assume that `maxDbNumber` will only be called on non-empty lists, then you can use `foldr1` instead, which doesn't require a starting value. (This is n.m.'s first scenario, where you decide you don't care what happens if the input is empty.)

Comment: You can simplify this a bit, though, by discarding everything except `DbNumber` values before you start computing a maximum, in which case you can just use `maximum [z | DbNumber z <- xs]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not terribly elegant, but not complicated either—you could use the fact that `Nothing < Just x` for any `x`:

```
foldr (\x acc -> case x of
  DbNumber z -> Just z `max` acc
  _ -> acc) Nothing xs
```

This could be written a little more compactly by defining a function to extract the number if present:

```
fromDbNumber :: DatabaseItem -> Maybe Integer
fromDbNumber (DbNumber z) = Just z
fromDbNumber _ = Nothing

maxDbNumber = foldr (max . fromDbNumber) Nothing
```

The point-free `max . fromDbNumber` is derived like so:

```
-- Original:
\x acc -> max (fromDbNumber x) acc

-- Eta-reduce:
\x -> max (fromDbNumber x)

-- Definition of ‘(.)’:
max . fromDbNumber
```

This changes the result to `Maybe Integer`, of course, but this is appropriate: you need to do *something* to handle the case where there is no maximum, even if it’s just returning a default value.